# Adding comment in Late answers brings audit to fail?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I've just faced [this "Late Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8583871), I saw the quality of the post is good, but as far as I know that topic and I found a small mistake in the answer I wanted to add comment, but when pressed "Add comment" - I failed the audit.
Does *StackOverflow* think the comment is added only to bad question or why is it so?